# Altering a flexbox layout to display block format

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a section in which is displaying via a flex box. This works great, but when the viewport gets to a 640px or less size, I want to be able to make all three section be shown in a `display: block` fashion with a width of 100%. I tried changing the `#contact-section` to `display: block`, but it went completely out of the format I have with `flex`.

I am wanting it to appear like this under 640px's.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can do it without losing the flex format, or at least making it work in this viewport?

[Here is a fiddle which will allow the sections to be seen in a 640 or less viewport.](https://jsfiddle.net/mq41hgkp/)

```css
#contact-section {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 color: #FFF;
 background: #00a16d;
 padding: 1em;
}
#contact-section:before {
 content: "";
 flex: 0 0 1px;
 height: 3em;
 background: #FFF;
 order: 2;
}
#contact-section-left {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 order: 1;
 font-style: italic;
}
#contact-section-right {
 background: url("../icons/envelope.png") center / contain no-repeat;
 font-size: 2em;
 order: 3;
 padding: 1em 0;
}
#contact-section-right a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*--------------------------MEDIA QUERY 640------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

#contact-section {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1em 2em;
}
#contact-section:before {
 flex: 0 0 1px;
 height: 3em;
 order: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact-section-left {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 order: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact-section-right {
 font-size: 2em;
 order: 3;
 padding: 1em 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
 
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-left">Tell us more about your digital marketing project.</div>
  <div id="contact-section-right"><a href="../discuss-project">Contact us</a></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed the direction to column, seems that now it works

```css
#contact-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #00a16d;
  padding: 1em;
}
#contact-section:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 1px;
  height: 3em;
  background: #FFF;
  order: 2;
}
#contact-section-left {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  order: 1;
  font-style: italic;
}
#contact-section-right {
  background: url("../icons/envelope.png") center / contain no-repeat;
  font-size: 2em;
  order: 3;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
#contact-section-right a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*--------------------------MEDIA QUERY 640------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #contact-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }
  #contact-section:before {
    flex: 0 0 10px;
    order: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  #contact-section-left {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    order: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #contact-section-right {
    font-size: 2em;
    order: 3;
    padding: 1em 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-left">Tell us more about your digital marketing project.</div>
  <div id="contact-section-right"><a href="../discuss-project">Contact us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I can center the "Contact us" into the image? Right now the image is centered, but the contact us is aligned left.

Comment: Also, anyway to get the `order: 2`; pseudo white line to appear?

Comment: It's not really the Contact us that is not aligned, it's the a inside. Added text-align: center to section-right, now it's centered. And at least in Chrome, the pseudo is showing ... I will check in FF and IE

Comment: Ahh.. I though the space-around would center the align-items would have centered it without that. Ok, I added `text-align:center`, but I am using Chrome and the pseudo element is not display in the media query.

Comment: I just don't understand why you don't see the pseudo ... I have made it red and bigger, just in case. It works in FF and IE, I just checked

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, the `width: 100%` wasn't added to that element. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `min-width` instead mediaqueries and `flex-wrap:wrap` and eventually  `border(s)`  on the first element to drop the pseudo `::before`. See  [Fiddle test 1](https://jsfiddle.net/mq41hgkp/1/) & [Fiddle test 2](https://jsfiddle.net/mq41hgkp/2/) .

```css
#contact-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #00a16d;
}
#contact-section:before {} #contact-section-left {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  min-width: 320px;
  border-top: 1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
}
#contact-section-right {
  background: url("../icons/envelope.png") center / contain no-repeat;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 320px;
}
#contact-section-right a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-section">
  <div id="contact-section-left">Tell us more about your digital marketing project.</div>
  <div id="contact-section-right"><a href="../discuss-project">Contact us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**edit**

if you still want to use a pseudo of 3em height, then you can draw it from the first box https://jsfiddle.net/mq41hgkp/3/

Comment: Thank you. The only thing about doing it this way is it loses the centering that I had for each section.

Comment: @Paul you only need to add it , this is secondary and text-align:center is efficient there, or imbricate an extra level of flex with align-items and justify-content. I may make an example if that is not clear for you :)

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I can center the "Contact us" into the image? Right now the image is centered, but the contact us is aligned left. Also, any way to get the pseudo element white line to appear?